# How to generate CSU(Card Status Update) in EMV chip CVN 18 card version response message

Tags: credit-card

In credit cards, for EMV chip cards CVN 10 (card version), when end-user initiates the transaction via POS terminal, from Visa we receive the

**request message**
0100 - request message with field 55 (EMv chip info like ARQC value, ATC value, etc).

**Response message:-**
0110 - response message we send ARPC value (It will have 8-byte ARPC Cryptogram and ARPC response code)

Same like above we have CVN 18 cards, where we receive ARQC in 0100 messages in Feild F55. after ARQC validation we send back a response to visa in the below format.

CVN 18 , ARPC format.
[image]

How these CSU values will be generated.

Do we send default values or based on card validation we send CSU values?

CSU default values as per Visa manual.

[image]

Comment: CSU is constructed by the Issuer and specifies what actions to be executed by the chip at the transaction completion. For example there is a possibility to block the card/application or reset PIN try counter, etc. Using the CSU the issuer can simplify its post-issuance processing replacing the heavy post-issuance commands like CARD BLOCK, PIN UNBLOCK.
Check the online CSU builder tool https://paymentcardtools.com/emv-misc/csu for the possible features.